# Fourier transformation of sin, cos, sinh and cosh

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

I am trying to solve the following exercise

> Use $\mathcal{F}(e^{xb}) = 2\pi \delta_{ib}$ to calculate the Fourier-Transformation of $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\sinh x$ and $\cosh x$

Now I am a little bit confused, because the fourier transformation of $\sin x$ is simply $\sin x$, of $\cos x$ is $\cos x$, of $\sinh x$ it is $-i \sin(ix)$ and of $\cosh(x)$ it is $\cos(ix)$ simply by definition, so why should I use the relation $\mathcal{F}(e^{xb}) = 2\pi \delta_{ib}$?

Comment: "The Fourier transform of $\sin(x)$ is $\sin(x)$"? What definition are you using?

Comment: that it is an infinity sum of sin- and cos terms

Comment: You're thinking of the Fourier series.

Comment: ah, ok you mean the integral with $e^{-i\xi x}$ ok, then i think i know how to calculate it!

Comment: @Stefan is an infinity sum of polynomials still a polynomial?

Comment: i think not....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there are formulae:
$$\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\quad\cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2$$
$$\sinh x=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}2\quad\cosh x=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}2$$
Use them and the Fourier transform of $e^{bx}$